# Angularjs $http promise; Get the callback functions fn1 and fn2 from $http().then(fn1, fn2)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular-promise

I am doing a custom Oauth2 authentication module. I have a requestExecutor factory:

```
     $http({
        url: requestObject.url, 
        method: requestObject.method, 
        cache: requestObject.cache, 
        headers: requestObject.headers, 
        data: requestObject.data})

        .then(function (resData) {
           if (requestObject.callback) {
               requestObject.callback(resData.data);
           }
         }, function () {
           if (requestObject && requestObject.customErrorCallback) {
               requestObject.customErrorCallback();
           }
        });
```

and Http Interceptor:

```
'responseError': function (rejection) {
       console.log(rejection)
       switch (rejection.status) {
               case 401 :
               {
                  $rootScope.$emit(CONST.UNAUTHORIZED);
                  break;
               }
               case 403 :
               {
                  $rootScope.$emit(CONST.FORBIDDEN, rejection.config);
                  break;
               }
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
       }
```

So when I execute a request and get 403 response error 
from the server I want to send the full request to the listener of `CONST.FORBIDDEN` (the only thing that is missing is the callbacks from the `$http().then()` promise). The reason is that I want to execute the failed request again after I finish with the refreshing the access token.

My questions are:

1. Where are stored `$http().then()` promises?
2. Can to get `$http().then()` promises?
3. How can I implement 2.?

Comment: No, I don't think you can. And you shouldn't. Can't you make your interceptor fulfill/reject the original `$http(…)` promise?

Comment: @Bergi Sure, but I want an separate module for the error handling that does not depend on anything. Just when an 403 error - `$emit` the original request as it was used in the `$http` along with the callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure about your intention, there would probably be better solutions, but you can register the callback handlers in the config object and access them in the interceptor. [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UobVmdoYWbx91bNZqsVp?p=preview)

But here is a better design. [angular-app/securityInterceptor](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/security/interceptor.js)
You will do the refreshing in the interceptor and execute the request again. If the second request was successful you return the result, which will be processed by your success/error-handlers.

```
$scope.fetchAsync = function(forceError) {
    function successHandler(result) {
        $scope.content = result.data;
    }

    function errorHandler(result) {
        $scope.content = result;
    }   

    $scope.content = 'Loading...';

    $http.get(forceError ? 'not-found' : 'test.txt', {
      handler: {
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
      }
    }).then(successHandler, errorHandler);
}

$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return {
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            console.log(rejection.config.handler);
            return rejection;
        }
    };
});
```